# The pdf is not loaded when I try to add image

Tags: php, image, yii2, mpdf

I'm trying to use **mpdf** and it works fine with text but when I try to add an image to my pdf file the page is infinitely loading and nothing happens. I just see the browser page. 
When I delete the image, it works fine again and pdf file is created and could be downloaded.

The path to the image is right, I checked on the other simple view page without mpdf.
Here is current result that I see when add an image:
(https://i.ibb.co/KyfmvpN/2019-07-16-23-39-14.png)

I will be glad for any help, please!

Here is the controller:

```
public function actionCreateMPDF()
{
  $mpdf = new mPDF();
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('mpdf'));
  $mpdf->Output();
  exit;
}

public function actionForceDownloadPdf()
{
 $mpdf = new mPDF();
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('mpdf'));
 $mpdf->Output('MyPDF.pdf', 'D');
 exit;
}
```

and the view file where I am creating my pdf **mpdf.php**:

```
<p>Hello</p> 
<img src="/images/top.png">
```

Comment: what are the contents of the `mpdf` view you are rendring please add here and try using the `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;` to see if there are any image related errors.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam my view is only this two rows: <p>Hello</p> 
<img src="/images/top.png">

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I tried to add $mpdf->showImageErrors = true; but where should I find this errors?  There is nothing in terminal and I cannot see the page code and console because page isn't loaded:(

Comment: First, try upgrading to the last mPDF version. That may help by more verbose error messages (check PHP error logs) or even Exceptions with `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by deleting the **width:100%** from the div(where img tag was located) style and putting it directly to the **img**  tag styling.